# Change window location if input value is string

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, location, window

I'm trying to make like a mini Google.
Where you write in Facebook or Instagram to an input and when you click the button "search" you will be sent over to that page.
So far I've got this, but it only goes to Facebook.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var search = document.getElementById("search")

btn.onclick = function (){

    if (search.value == "Facebook" || "facebook"){
        window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/";

    } else if( search.value == "Instagram" || "instagram"){
        window.location = "https://www.instagram.com/";
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text"/>
<button id="btn" type="button">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your `if`s, `if (search.value == "Facebook" || "facebook")` is like saying

> if `search.value == "Facebook"` is true, or `"facebook"` is true, do

Which doesn't work, because `"facebook"` will always be true and thus the second `if` for Instagram is never entered.

Instead, what you want is

> if `search.value == "Facebook"` is true, or if `search.value == "facebook"` is true, do

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var search = document.getElementById("search")

btn.onclick = function (){

    if (search.value == "Facebook" || search.value == "facebook"){
        window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/";

    } else if( search.value == "Instagram" || search.value == "instagram"){
        window.location = "https://www.instagram.com/";
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text"/>
<button id="btn" type="button">Search</button>
```

Comment: You won't see the website because they prohibit your browser from displaying them in an iframe.